# coordinate transformation from $S = \{(u,v)\}\big|0\leq u,v \leq 1\}$ to $D = \{(x,y)\big| 0\leq y\leq2;|x|\leq \frac{y^2}{4}-1 \}$

Tags: calculus

$S = \{(u,v)\}\big|0\leq u,v \leq 1\}$

$D = \{(x,y)\big| 0\leq y\leq2;\big|x\big|\leq \big|\frac{y^2}{4}-1 \big|\}$

My teacher said S and D has figure like this：
[image]

**Q1:How to prove this formula is the right figure????**

apply transform 
$$\Phi:
\begin{cases}
x = u^2+v^2\\
y = 2uv
\end{cases}$$
can transform from S to D.

**Q2:How to make use of $\Phi$ and $D = \{(x,y)\big| 0\leq y\leq2;\big|x\big|\leq \big|\frac{y^2}{4}-1 \big|\}$
to obtain this?** $$S = \{(u,v)\}\big|0\leq u,v \leq 1\}$$
Update: I change the formula of D to 
$$|x|\leq \big| \frac{y^2}{4}-1 \big|$$
I plot a figure in matlab, and now it's much more lick the PPT's figure:

```
ezplot('abs(y^2/4-1)=abs(x)')
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you wanting to ask how to prove that $\Phi[S]=D$?

Comment: You are correct in that your equation of $D$ doesn't describe the picture of $D$. Maybe the teacher meant $|x| \leq \left| \frac{y^2}{4} - 1 \right|$ and not $|x| \leq \frac{y^2}{4} - 1$? Also, $\Phi$ surely doesn't transform $S$ to $D$ as depicted in the picture.

Comment: @GitGud Yes , I mean how to prove that?

Comment: @levap You are right, after add abs value at the right side:$$|x|\leq \big| \frac{y^2}{4}-1 \big|$$  I plot a figure in matlab much more like the one of D in my question, I've updated my question.

Comment: @Long Well, it's not true. Take for instance $\Phi(1,1)$. It's not in $D$ even though $(1,1)\in S$.